# Call setter and getter from static method

Tags: php, class, static

I am currently a little bit confused with static and setters/Getters ins php.

My code is as following:

```
class Test{

private static $name;

   public static function setName( $value ){
     self::$name = $value //Works fine
    }

   public static function getName(){
     return self::$name;
   }

   function something(){
       self:: setName('nameOne');
   }

   public static function dostuff(){
       $test = self::getName(); //var_dump returns NULL
   }
}
```

How can I get the value of `$name` inside the function `dostuff`, which has to be static?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Your function `something()` is not valid. You can't use `$this->setName()` you should use `self::SetName()`. To get you value in `dostuff()` just call it like `$myname = self::$name`

Comment: You can use `self` to refer to class properties. So in your case it would be: `self::name`. Also you can't you `$this` in a static context.

Comment: Quite honestly, it seems you don't really understand what `static` does. Why do these methods need to be static?!

Comment: The function has to be static, because it is given that way.

I updated the code as seen above, but i still can't get the value i store.

Answer (score 4):

you can access it with `self::getName()`.
by the way, the `something` methods looks wrong, it should be `self::setName('test')` instead of `$this->setName('test')`

EDIT: how do you call your methods ?
`something()` is not static, so you have to make an object with it, and then call `dostuff()` statically
also, your `something()` methods must be `public`, otherwise it will not be part of the class !
try this :

```
$myTest = new Test();
$myTest->something();
Test::dostuff();
```

this code works fine for me :

```
<?php
class Test{

    private static $name;

   public static function setName( $value ){
     self::$name = $value; //Works fine
    }

   public static function getName(){
     return self::$name;
   }

   public function something(){
       self::setName('nameOne');
   }

   public static function dostuff(){
       $test = self::getName(); //var_dump returns NULL
       echo $test."\n";
   }
}

$myTest = new Test();
$myTest->something();
Test::dostuff();
?>
```

Comment: HI! Thank you for your answer, but I can't make it work.
The code above is actually used for a wordpress plugin I am developing.
So the class Test is called on setup. 
setName() is being called on a specific hook, where a variable $name is filled with content and the should be made available for different functions:

The problem is that the function something() is also called on a specific hook, which means that i can not use Test::dostuff().
Furthermore the only function that has to be static is dostuff(), because the hook requires it that way.

I am out of ideas, anyone who can help?

Comment: Kinda hard to understand... can you edit your question to make it clear (where you can add line break and code tags. What is difficult to understand is the time line of your events. Can you try to explain this please ? I also don't understand why you wouldn't be able to call Test::dostuff()... it should be callable everywhere, even if an other piece of code uses an object of class Test...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to access it using `self`:

```
   public static function dostuff(){
      return "<p>Hello!, My name is:" . self::$name . "</p>"; 
   }
```

And I suggest removing:

```
   function something(){
      $this-> setName( 'test' );
   }
```

Since the method setName is static, you cant access it through an instance of the class.